# Showing certain topological spaces have only finitely many possible iso classes of n-sheeted coverings

Tags: general-topology, algebraic-topology, covering-spaces

Definition: We say an open cover of a topological space is "good" if every intersection of elements of the cover is either contractible or empty.

I would like to prove the following:

Claim: if $X$ is compact and admits a "good" open cover, then for each integer $n>0$, $X$ admits only finitely many isomorphism classes of (possibly disconnected) $n$-sheeted coverings.

Proof attempt:

Using the "good" property with compactness, we can find a finite good cover $U_1,\ldots,U_k$ of $X$. (A subcover of a good cover is still good.)

At this point, I would like to say every isomorphism class of $k$-sheeted covering of $X$ can be described by a collection $\{f_{ji} : F\rightarrow F\}_{i,j=1}^{k}$ of "gluing bijections" describing how to glue $U_i \times F$ with $U_j \times F$ on $(U_i \cap U_j) \times F$ in each space, satisfying a "cocycle condition"
$f_{\ell j} \circ f_{ji} = f_{\ell i}$ for every $1\leq i,j,\ell \leq k$; here $F$ is a fixed $n$-element discrete space, the "fiber" of the covering.

Would anyone know how to formulate this argument precisely?

Comment: I expect you could identify points in different fibers with the path lifting property. Since intersections of the open sets are contractible, all paths you might pick are in the same homotopy class or some such thing.

Comment: I think [this proof of van Kampen's theorem](https://www3.nd.edu/~andyp/notes/SeifertVanKampen.pdf) is relevant.

Comment: Also a different argument: $X$ is homotopy equivalent to the nerve of a finite good cover, so $\pi_1(X)$ is finitely generated. So $\pi_1(X)$ only has finitely many subgroups of a given index, which proves the statement for connected coverings. But each connected component of a covering must be a covering, and there are only finitely many partitions of $d$.